# easiest static model format to load with java?

Tags: java, model, 3d, loader

What's the easiest static (non-animating) 3d model format to load with Java? I used .obj in C++, but that's a pain to do in java. Is there anything better?

Comment: The obj format is plain text and should be pretty easy to load in any language. What problems are you having?

Comment: also google has many resources of java loaders for 3ds, obj, and others

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the engine you are using to display that model more than the language used to read the file.  Java can read a .obj file just as easily as C++ can.

Engines such as [jMonkeyEngine](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com) can load [3DS, MD2, MD3, MS3D, OBJ and X3D](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/wiki/doku.php?id=model_loading).  Plenty of formats, none of which you need to write code for.

There are many other engines also, the googletrons will help with that.